# Grails how to dynamically search based on varying search parameters

Tags: grails, groovy

Let's say we have to perform a search on a bunch of database records and the search criteria is defined by a few check boxes and a text field. So, if check box for 'US Citizen' is checked and the textfield 'name' is filled with "John Doe". Then my search in my Grails application will be something like:

```
def results = IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(citizenship: 'US', name: 'John Doe')
```

now, if someone also checks the box 'voter' then I'll change my search to:

```
def results = IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(citizenship: US, name: 'John Doe', voter: true)
```

In reality my application has a couple of text fields and 6 checkboxes. Obviously I cannot write a custom search function based on each different combination of criteria there's just too many combinations. What would be an efficient way to tackle this problem? So, I guess ideally there would be one search function that could take in the customized query parameters and search with those. I'm a bit lost and confused. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue with using a Criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In reality my application has a couple of text fields and 6 checkboxes. Obviously I cannot write a custom search function based on each different combination of criteria there's just too many combinations

You don't really need to concern yourself with handling the combinations. If you can receive the field names and values as a Map, you can simply pass the Map to `findAllWhere`, e.g.

```
def search(Map predicates) {
  IndividualRecord.findAllWhere(predicates)
}
```

If for some reason you don't like this approach, you can use a criteria query instead, e.g.

```
def search(Map predicates) {

  IndividualRecord.withCriteria {

    if (predicates.voter != null) {
      eq 'voter', predicates.voter
    }

    if (predicates.citizenship) {
      eq 'citizenship', predicates.citizenship
    }

    if (predicates.name) {
      eq 'name', predicates.name
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not used a criteria before so I wasn't sure how it's used and what it is. That's awesome guidance. I will try it.